# How to draw rounded rectangle shape items in a listview

Tags: android, listview

How to draw a rounded rectangle shape in listview for each item.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **shape**. It can be done easily via xml. Set **android:background="@drawable/rounded_rows"** to your view.

rounded_rows.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<!-- view background color -->
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" >
</solid>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners android:radius="10dp" >
</corners>
```

Answer (score 0):

first a create file Xml in drawable with name:rounded.xml
and edit below code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#003344" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"  

    android:topRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
```

if you want to have rounded for each items..
you should create custom listView and edit above code to layout...

Answer (score 0):

try this code.
  create a xml file and put this on "Drawable" folder with any name like "bg_list_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp" /> 

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#666666" />

</shape>
```

use use this as a background for listview items.

use like  `android:background="@drawable/bg_list_view"`

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml do the following:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/something"
        android:centerColor="@color/something_else"
        android:startColor="@color/something_else_still"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

You can change the amount of "rounding" of the corners by changing the **android:radius**